# Mapping data above 90th percentile with cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, spatial, python-xarray, cartopy

I am still fairly new to programming and python in particular.

I have spatial dust optical depth data, with dimensions of lat, lon, and time.

I have managed to make daily plots of a dust plume as it moves across the Atlantic, and now I am trying to make similar plots masking out any cell below the 90th percentile value.

I have an array of 90th percentile values created with the following code:

```
#====== select and average over study region ======#
tropatl_mjjas = dod_2.sel(latitude=slice(25, 8), longitude=slice(270, 342)).mean(dim=('latitude', 'longitude'))

#====== resample to daily then drop NAN ======#
tropatl_mjjas_daily = tropatl_mjjas.resample(time='D').mean(dim='time').dropna(dim='time')

#====== reshape to 17 rows x 153 columns ======#
tropatl_2d = np.reshape(tropatl_mjjas_daily.values,(17, 153))

percvalues=np.zeros(92)
k=0
for i in range(24,152):
    if i==116:
        break
    ravel_1 = np.ravel(tropatl_2d[:, i:i+15])
    percvalues[k]=np.percentile(ravel_1, 90)
    k+=1
    
print(percvalues)
```

What I would like to do is somehow check each cell against the 90th percentile for that day in the study region. This particular dust event is 12 days long. I started with trying it for a single day:

```
data = dod.sel(time='2015-06-18').resample(time='D').mean(dim='time')
valid_data = data[data>percvalues[24]]
```

But I get this error: IndexError: 3-dimensional boolean indexing is not supported.

Here is what the data array looks like:
[data array][1] you can see the variable name is 'duaod550'

I tried it this instead:

```
valid_data = data[dod>percvalues[24]]
```

IndexError: Boolean array size 49672 is used to index array with shape (1,).

and

```
valid_data = data[duaod550>percvalues[24]]
```

NameError: name 'duaod550' is not defined

So how do I work around the dimension issues to make the code compare each cell to the 90th percentile value?

Thank you in advance for any help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1FHV.png